# Get data from parent row in child row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table (`PostgreSQL`) which looks like:

```
id  parentid  name   gradeA gradeB
1              I-1    5       20
2              I-2    5        30
3     1        I-3    17       50
4     1        I-4    5        12
```

I want to get all rows that has `gradeA=5` but, if a row has parentid I want that under grade I will see the grades of the parent.

meaning I want to get:

```
id  parentid  name   gradeA gradeB
1              I-1    5       20
2              I-2    5        30
4     1        I-4    5        20     /gradeA and gradeB are if id=1 not id=4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to self join your table on the `parentid` field from one table and the `id` of the other table.  I used `COALESCE()` to choose `gradeA` and `gradeB` from the parent table if they are present, and to default to the child values if they are not present.

```
SELECT g1.id, g1.parentid, g1.name
    COALESCE(g2.gradeA, g1.gradeA) AS gradeA, COALESCE(g2.gradeB, g1.gradeB) AS gradeB
FROM grades g1 LEFT JOIN grades g2
    ON g1.parentid = g2.id
WHERE g1.gradeA = 5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT g1.id, g1.parentid, g1.name, g1.gradeA,
       coalesce(g2.gradeB, g1.gradeB) AS gradeB
FROM grades g1
LEFT JOIN grades g2 ON g2.id = g1.parentid
WHERE g1.gradeA = 5;
```